# How to fire the day and week button view press through code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to intercept the pressure of `day` and `week` button on `FullCalendar` but seems doesn't work, this is my code for the `day` button:

```
$('body').on('click', '#fc-multiColAgendaDay-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left', function()
{
      alert("Try!");
}),
```

for more details this are the button:

[image]

**HTML code**

```
<button type="button" class="fc-multiColAgendaDay-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-state-active">Giorno</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong classes, change `#` to `.`. Its not ID, its class name. Also remove spaces in class names.

```
$('body').on('click', '.fc-multiColAgendaDay-button.fc-button.fc-state-default.fc-corner-left', function()
{
      alert("Try!");
}),
```